# Is there an algorithmic way to compute the quotient of two subgroups of $\mathbb Z^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, abelian-groups

In algebraic topology one sometimes has to compute the homology groups via CW complexes, reducing the problem to the calculation of $Z/B$ where $B \subseteq Z \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n $. It is difficult enough for me sometimes if $B$ is complicated.

For instance the isomorphism $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z / \left<(2,0),(-1,2)\right> \cong \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z $ is *not* trivial at all.

Is there a general algorithm to determine $Z/B$, as both of $Z$ and $B$ are represented as the subgroups generated by several elements of $\mathbb Z^n $? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For instance, you can use *Smith normal form* to do this. This amounts to doing Gaussian elimination over the integers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

In somewhat more detail, any subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}^n$ can be thought of as the image of a $\mathbf{Z}$-linear (that is, additive) map $\mathbf{Z}^m \to \mathbf{Z}^n$ for some integer $m$, which in turn may be represented by a matrix $A$ with integer entries. Performing elementary row operations on $A$ amounts to gradually changing the chosen basis of the target $\mathbf{Z}^n$, and performing elementary column operations on $A$ amounts to gradually changing the chosen basis of the domain $\mathbf{Z}^m$. The relevant fact is therefore that you can use elementary row and column operations to reduce $A$ to a diagonal matrix of the form
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix} a_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\ 0 & a_2 & 0 & \cdots \\ 0 & 0 & a_3 & \cdots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \end{matrix} \right)$$ in which $a_i$ divides $a_{i+1}$ for all $i$.

This is a computationally effective form of the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, and shows that the cokernel of $A$ is isomorphic to $$\mathrm{coker}(A) \cong \mathbf{Z}/a_1 \mathbf{Z} \oplus \mathbf{Z}/a_2 \mathbf{Z} \oplus \cdots.$$

In your chosen example, the matrix $A$ is
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix} -1 & 2 \\ 2 &  0 \end{matrix} \right)$$ and by first doing the row operation *replace row two by row two plus twice row one* and then the column operation *replace column two by column two plus twice column one* reduces it to
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 &  4 \end{matrix} \right),$$ showing that the cokernel is $\mathbf{Z}/4 \mathbf{Z}$ as claimed.